Can an XSD have two elements with same name whose type is determined by an attribute value
I need to make an XSD schema (version 1.0) that is used for creating XML files by our clients, and for validation of the XML by us. Is it possible to make a XSD schema for the following XML file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wrapper>
  <Parent Id="1" DeterminingAttribute="A">
    <Data>
      <base1></base1>
      <base2></base2>
      <A1></A1>
      <A2></A2>
    </Data>
  </Parent>
  <Parent Id="2" DeterminingAttribute="B">
    <Data>
      <base1></base1>
      <base2></base2>
      <B1></B1>
      <B2></B2>
    </Data>
  </Parrent>
</Wrapper>

Explanation: The type of the Parent element is determined by the value of DeterminingAttribute attribute.
If it is not possible, what would I need to change in order to make a valid XSD schema?
I have tried with the following schema which in Visual Studio says it has valid format, but when trying to validate XML files in code, it throws error like parent element of Parent element must have have more than 0 elements and that Data element is not valid.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Wrapper">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Parent" type="Parent-base"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Parent-base" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:unsignedInt"></xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Parent-spec-A">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Parent-base">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Data" type="Data-spec-A"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="DeterminingAttribute" type="xs:string" fixed="A"></xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Parent-spec-B">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="Parent-base">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Data" type="Data-spec-B"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="DeterminingAttribute" type="xs:string" fixed="B"></xs:attribute>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Data-spec-A">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="base1" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      <xs:element name="base2" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="A1" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
      <xs:element name="A2" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Data-spec-B">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="base1" type="xs:unsignedByte" />
      <xs:element name="base2" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="B1" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
      <xs:element name="B2" type="xs:unsignedShort" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>

Note: I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2
Edit 1: Searching the internet I've found out that the core tools like XmlReader used for processing XML in .NET, DO NOT SUPPORT XML/XSD 1.1.
So solution must be with version 1.0. Commercial plugins are not an option.

Might be possible in XSD 1.1 with https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative

It has to be XSD 1.0 unfortunately. Though thank you for the suggestion, I will have it on my mind for future reference.

If you're stuck with XSD 1.0, the only solution is to add supplementary validation using, for example, Schematron.

And if I could change the XML format, what would be the best way to do it? Just change the name of the Parent elements so they are of different type?

Or would I need to remove the Data element also?

As @MartinHonnen pointed out, what you need is directly supported by the XSD 1.1 Check it out here: https://www.xfront.com/xml-schema-1-1/xml-schema-1-1-for-managers.ppt?v=15

Note that the XSD shown wouldn't validate the XML shown for the simple reason that the nodes are spelled Parrent, with two rs... Probably just a typo in the question, but...

@HereticMonkey typo in the question
